# Whats the max geofence limit in Windows Mobile 10?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, geofencing

I can't seem to find an answer in official documentation. Does anybody know the geofence limit in WM10?

For example, Android limit is 100 and iOS is 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the UWP guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/guidelines-for-geofencing):

> Don't use more than 1000 geofences per app. The system actually supports thousands of geofences per app, you can maintain good app performance to help reduce the app's memory usage by using no more than 1000.

It also says in [the overview for the `Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geofencing` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geofencing) that:

> Windows and Windows Phone support hundreds of geofences per app.

This is basically one of those "if you have to ask, you have too many" questions.